# How to create a new entity with fields in CRM programatically

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to create a new Entity named "Record" with fields like ApprovalStatus, PendingWith.
How can I create it programatically a part of the solution so that I can deploy it to higher environments

I was able to find links for creating [new entity items](http://thecrmclub.blogspot.in/2013/08/crm-2011-step-by-step-how-to.html), but I want to create a new entity

I have to create few entities like Record,Management etc and I also need to create some views, forms for these 
What is the best approach for this?  I am using CRM 2016

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Metadata Web Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309539.aspx) to manipulate the CRM metadata and so create entities, with attributes. Specifically you are looking for functions like [CreateEntityRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createentityrequest.aspx).

However if you are looking to move components between environments you would be better served using [solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334576.aspx) which are explicitly for that purpose

Comment: Thanks for the details answer James
Yes I am looking for moving items like entities, forms, views between environments